# Java Soket Threaded Server sending messages back to specific client

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server

i am developing a Client-Server Java GUI(Swing) application , i have succsesfully created Threaded Server class that receives messages from clients , and a Client class that sends message to the server , both Client and Server are GUI applications , i am developing a lan ordering system for my internet caffe..
I am new to socket programing , what i need now is a way to send a message from Server to Client when user of Server GUI application views the order in a GUI by clicking a JLabel that changes icon when message arrives..

So how to send a message from the Server to that specific Client that send the message that triggered that specific JLabel ? And how to show JOptionpane to to Client user containing that message (client has several JPanel classes)

Client class that sends the message:

```
package questorderingsystem.engine;

import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    public class SendItemAndIp {

    private static Socket socket;
    public static String message = "";
    public static void sendToServer(String item) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    InetAddress IP= InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    String ipadr = IP.toString();
    String PCNUM = ipadr.substring(ipadr.length() - 2);

    //IP SERVERAA 
    String host = "192.168.55.151";
    int port = 1978;
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        socket = new Socket(address, port);
        //Send the message to the server
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        String oneLine = item.replace("\n", "%");
        String sendMessage = oneLine +"/"+ PCNUM;
        bw.write(sendMessage);
        bw.flush();
        socket.close();
}
}
```

Threaded Server

```
package questorderingsystemserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ThreadedEchoServer {

static final int PORT = 1978;

public static void startServer() {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket socket = null;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
        }
        // new thread for a client
        new EchoThread(socket).start();
    }
}
}
```

EchoServer

```
package questorderingsystemserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class EchoThread extends Thread {
protected Socket socket;



}
public EchoThread(Socket clientSocket) {
    this.socket = clientSocket;
}
public void run() {
    InputStream inp = null;
    BufferedReader brinp = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        inp = socket.getInputStream();
        brinp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inp));
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }
    String line;
    while (true) {
        try {
            line = brinp.readLine();
            if ((line == null) || line.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT")) {
                socket.close();
                return;
            } else {
                //do something

                out.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EchoThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I can send the entire project if necessary , just i dont know where to upload it ?

Comment: It seems like you close the client connection as soon as the client sends data. How is that client supposed to receive data back from the server if the client closed it's connection to the server?

Comment: According to @VinceEmigh you should create one socket per client and use it during the entire lifetime of your client application.

Comment: ok so i remove socket.close in client class ? then read input in client like i read in server from client ? but how to target the specific client from server ? @VinceEmigh

Comment: Should the task be synchronus? Meaning that you await the response of the server before proceeding with the programm or asynchronus? could you provide the 'reading logic' of your Client?

Answer (score 0):

Sockets establish end-to-end-connections and therefore each socket it connected to another **specific** one. A `ServerSocket` is slightly different. Take a look at the return of [`ServerSocket::accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()). The returned object is a `Socket`. Not only one socket but the one directly connected to the client who issued a request. Since you create a new `EchoThread` for each `ServerSocket#accept` call each `EchoThread` has it's of connection to it's own Client.

You're already reading from the socket to check if the connection has been closed or 'QUIT command' has been issued. Now you can simply respond in your `else`-clause with the `DataOutputStream` created earlier:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        line = brinp.readLine();
        if ((line == null) || line.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT")) {
            socket.close();
            return;
        } else {
            //writing here:
            out.write("Some response text\n".getBytes());
            out.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      ...
    } ...
}
```

But note that your repsonse String needs to end with a `'\n'` character, depending on your 'reading logic' of your client.

Comment: how to do out.write("adasd\n".getBytes()); from gui of the server , and how to read that msg in client ? @L.Spillner

Comment: @AleksandarStojanovic That does strongly depend on your project structure and your desired behaviour. In terms of GUIs I would often go with the [MVP pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) but you might have another implementation currently. And how to "read" the response depends on many factors. If it is synchronus or asynchronus, the time you  want to read and so on and I can't help you with that. But for sure is that you always have to use the same socket per connection.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done, as you specified the first command as "QUIT", so you may implement more commands as you wish.

The good part is handling the input and output using the `BufferedReader` and `DataOutputStream`.

Please note if you like to work with strings for communication between client and server, so you may go for `PrintStream` or `PrintWriter` instead of `DataOutputStream`.

in thread server file/class, place this line `new EchoThread(socket).start();` after you accept the socket in side the try(it's now safe).

In client class/file, as you send some command for server, then you may expecting some result too. So just like echo class you created, you may do the same thing for client and process the responses.